# Dynamic Variable Name smarty

Tags: math, variables, dynamic, smarty

I want to add up numbers, that come out of an array in smarty.
The following code shows the total price of every different product in a shoppingcart.

```
{foreach name=aussen item=data from=$cart_data}
{$data.products_final_price.plain}
{/foreach}
```

Is there a way to add up all of the single numbers?

I thought of something like giving every {$data.products_final_price.plain} variable a different name, depending on the amount of loops the foreach went through. For example: number1 number2 number3 and than adding them up with smarty math equation.

I figured out how to use the counter but not how to give my Variable a different name each time it loops.

That sounds confusing...

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Smarty3:

```
{$foo = 0}
{foreach name=aussen item=data from=$cart_data}
  {$foo = $foo + $data.products_final_price.plain}
{/foreach}
```

Smarty 2:

```
{assign var="foo" value=0}
{foreach name=aussen item=data from=$cart_data}
  {assign var"foo"  value=$foo+$data.products_final_price.plain}
{/foreach}
```

If you're stuck with Smarty2, consider using [{math}](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.math.tpl) for more complex equations